# Can I put a border radius on a before or after pseudo selector image?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can get a border-radius on a :before or :after when I put an image url() in the content:'' property?

Comment: What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Here is an image of what I am getting: http://puu.sh/gnCUu/302d26093b.png
As you see, the black border becomes rounded when I add the border radius property, but the image does not. I would like to make the IMAGE rounded (I don't plan to have the black border at all)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use `border-radius` in pseudo-elements `::after`, `::before` with an background image:

```css
div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x100);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set border-radius in Your CSS rule, for `:before` or `:after` element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpz9nzq4/)

```
#container {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#container:before {

    content: '';
    background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc6a0c03b68') blue;
    background-size: 1000px auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It seems, I was using the zoom property to size, and had the image in the content property - when moving it to the background property, I found it was disappearing because I didn't put a width and height on it. Problem solved now, thanks.