# How to rounded an image whatever the source shape and size?

Tags: html, css

In my ionic/angularJS app i'm using either the camera or the gallery to pick a photo and upload it as avatar. My problem is, depending the source file, if the image is small or rectangle, i'm not able to resize it the way i want to have a proper rounded image. What do you think ?

Here is what i have :

[image]

Or here, same image but it's too much zoomed in...
[image]

```css
/* ZOOMED IN IMAGE CSS */

.menu-image-2 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.menu-image-2 > img {
   width: 150px;
   border-radius: 0%;
}

figure{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
  left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* CROPPED IMAGE CSS */

.moncompte-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.moncompte-image > img {
  max-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

figure_monCompte{

}

figure_monCompte > img{
  max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!--ZOOMED IN IMAGE -->
 
 <div class="menu-image-2">
    <figure><img data-ng-src="xxxxx"></figure>
</div>


 <!-- CROPPED IMAGE -->
 
<div class="moncompte-image">
     <figure_monCompte>
           <img src="xxxxxx">         </figure_monCompte>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

I have a question about the second snippet, I would like to use it, but i need to set the background image out of the css file, but when trying this the image is not set as background so the result is an image squeezed instead of have a nice hidden overflow... Do you have ideas to overtake this ?

```css
#rounded-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#rounded-image:before {
    content: "";
    /* background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7xWxpunlZ2w/maxresdefault.jpg) center; */
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <img data-ng-src="{{avatar}}" id="rounded-image">
```

Comment: You can just put `border-radius:50%;` on your images... and they should do what you want.

Comment: How are you loading the image into it?

Comment: You can do inline styles too... if you can get Angular to pass the path to the image, url through, then use inline styles to add it to the DOM Element ...

Comment: Actually, scratch that... you need it as the :before element... sooo, you need to do styles within the page, but not inline... and not on the image.. you need to use a DIV or similar, I don't think psuedo elements work on images. Could be wrong.

Comment: I'll add to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the image as background-image, background position center, background size contain, top left 0, background repeat no repeat

If you dont specify the image as background image, the image might get stretched

*Sorry for the formatting, im stuck in a traffic only with my phone

Comment: Let me know how you would do this when you'll be out of the traffic ! ;)
I have no idea how to achieve this, I thought  using the css ` > img` was already treated the image as a background...

Comment: So how would you do that ? :)

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned in my comment, you can just use `border-radius: 50%;` but you may want to include browser prefixes:

```
img {
      border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

Browser prefixes: https://lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

```html
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/h9mYY0/moz.png" style="border-radius:50%;border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
```

Alternatively, you can use Psuedo elements, to set the images as the background images of the `::before` element... this way, you're `DIV` border radius will work correctly: [Can I put a border radius on a before or after pseudo selector image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883889/can-i-put-a-border-radius-on-a-before-or-after-pseudo-selector-image)

Or as the background image of the DIV itself, though this leaves you with less flexibility.

New snippet using Psuedo elements, works with rectangles and small images:

```css
#rounded-image {
      border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#rounded-image:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/9947/production/_103893293_ec317eb7-0fa2-4ec8-ab8e-53c9ce976a63.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounded-image"></div>
```

UPDATE:

```
<style>
#rounded-image:before {
        background-image: url('{{bgImg}}');
}
</style>
<div id="rounded-image"></div>
```

Obviously, you still need your CSS file for the rest of the styles, but do that in the `<head>` of your page, or just before the tag, but `<head>` is nicer ... *childish giggle*

Comment: we no more need prefix for border-radius, it's useless .. and he's already using border-radius

Comment: He's using it on the div not the image, and brilliant, that's good to know!

Comment: Erf, no it doesn't work the way i would. The image is not resized, any new suggestions ? :/

Comment: I've added another snippet getting it working with Psuedo elements which will be easier for you.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes on this other than bitterness or complete lack of actual CSS knowledge! But this is stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you have any luck implementing this?

Comment: I didn't downvote you ! What a shame to someone who had answers to downvote those who gives them...?! I didn't keep your css solution because i need my image url coming from an angularJS binding value. So it's better to crop directly the image instead. Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: I know, just the random StackOverflow fairies, happens on lots of good answers from lots of people.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: I have a question about the second snippet you gave me, I would like to use it, but i need to set the background image out of the css file, but when trying this the image is not set as background so the result is an image squeezed instead of have a nice hidden overflow... I edited my first post to show you the problem. Thank you ;)